# Getting 500 internal server error when web service call is made

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have created a web service in ColdFusion 9 running on Windows 2008 Server. Other application from outside the network is trying to access it via SOAP request which results in failure. I have logging enabled in my web service code which works fine when I'm testing on my end.

Is there a way to log network traffic to reproduce\capture this error on your system. Fiddler & Wireshark would capture traffic to the browser, but we need to capture server to server communications.

**EDIT1:** Adding log from client side which they get when they call web service.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
        <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
        <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
    </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Soap response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
   <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class java.lang.String -&gt; class java.util.Calendar)</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns1:stackTrace xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class java.lang.String -&gt; class java.util.Calendar)
.at org.apache.axis.message.RPCHandler.onStartChild(RPCHandler.java:286)
.at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
.at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
.at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
.at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
.at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
.at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:148)
.at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
.at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCProvider.invoke(CFCProvider.java:54)
.at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
.at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
.at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
.at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
.at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
.at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
.at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doAxisPost(CFCServlet.java:270)
.at coldfusion.filter.AxisFilter.invoke(AxisFilter.java:43)
.at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:363)
.at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
.at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
.at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:87)
.at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
.at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
.at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
.at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
.at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:138)
.at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doPost(CFCServlet.java:289)
.at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
.at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
.at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
.at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
.at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
.at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
.at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
.at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
.at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
.at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
.at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
.at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
.at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
.at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
.at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
.at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
.at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
.at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
</ns1:stackTrace>
    <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">SERVERNAME</ns2:hostname>
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: " which results in failure". Do you not have anything more to give us to work with than that? Your web server can/does log all through traffic, and the CF server logs all errors. But if the requests aren't even getting that far (you're being too vague to determine this), then you'll need to check if from the client-end perspective. If you yourself can't replicate this (from outside the system), you're gonna have to ask the ppl at the other end to give you some more information.

Comment: Added client-end server log.

Comment: Right, so given you've clearly communicated with the client, did you also ask them what the request was they were making, and what parameters they were passing, and how?

Comment: I have confirmed passed parameters with the values and datatypes. They match with what I am expecting. As of now they are calling my service using a tool called WebStudio.

Comment: They might be what *you're* expecting, but they sure ain't what your code is expecting, judging by that error. It looks to me (am no SOAP expert) like your service is expecting a Calendar, but it's being passed a string (which of course it would be, going over HTTP). How does one represent a Calendar object via WSDL? How are *you* calling this thing? (ie: the code).

Comment: Sometimes these errors on the page result in additional info being logged in CF's internal logs. Be sure and check the application.log, the exception.log, the server.log and also the standard "out" log (cfusion-out.log or *instance*-out.log) which is found in runtime/logs ... or a couple other locations all depending on your install config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing all the arguments to string instead of string, numeric and date did the trick (don't know why).
As of now I am accepting everything as string and then doing conversion at my end.